# What is wrong with my PACT Test and how to fix it?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, pact

I am writing a Pact Consumer and Provider Test .
Basically I have 3 problems at the moment.

```
 @Pact(provider = PROVIDER, consumer = CONSUMER)
    public RequestResponsePact getAddress(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
        PactDslJsonBody body = new PactDslJsonBody()
                .stringType("key1", "73501")
                .stringType("key2", "value");
        final Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Authorization","Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1");
        return builder
                .given("Something.")
                .uponReceiving("Dto")
                .path("/amz/ags")
                .query("code=9999")
                .method("GET")
                .headers(headers)
                .willRespondWith()
                .status(200)
                .body(body)
                .toPact();
    }
```

**1)** If I add a header in my Consumer Test I get a 500 status Error back

**2)** As you just saw in the Consumer I tried to add Authorisation Header , but in the Provider it will be expired, so I have to find a way to hack something and provide a valid token.

**3)** In the provider REST Api other services are getting called but it seems I have to mock them at least whenever they are called an Exception gets thrown. Honestly I also don't know how to do this. In which method I need to do it. Why at all do I have to mock them because the external Apis are running.

for 2) I found a solution

```
@TestTemplate
@ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
void pactVerificationTestTemplate(PactVerificationContext context, HttpRequest httpRequest) {
    httpRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi");
    context.verifyInteraction();
}
```

But now I get in context.verifyInteraction() an Exception. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the JVM specific question, however.

> 1. If I add a header in my Consumer Test I get a 500 status Error back

Usually, this means that you're told Pact you are going to do something but did not do it. In this case, my guess is the bearer token didn't match or it didn't receive the correct header. There should be logs or a junit report with the details.

> 2. As you just saw in the Consumer I tried to add Authorisation Header , but in the Provider it will be expired, so I have to find a way to hack something and provide a valid token.

For dealing with authentication/authorization, you may want to read the strategies here:
https://docs.pact.io/provider/handling_auth

> 3. In the provider REST Api other services are getting called but it seems I have to mock them at least whenever they are called an Exception gets thrown. Honestly I also don't know how to do this. In which method I need to do it. Why at all do I have to mock them because the external Apis are running.

Pact is intended to be closer to a unit test, running external services during Pact tests is not recommended, because it makes tests less deterministic. See also this section which discusses the provider test coverage: https://docs.pact.io/5-minute-getting-started-guide#scope-of-a-provider-pact-test.

Answer (score 0):

On the question of how to handle token expiry, I did like this.

The given:

- JWT token contains an `expire_at` claim

I wrote a small library to share within all the projects where I have a class like `JwtTestHelper` which generates any JWT with token `started_at` date as a **constant date** and `expire_at` is `started_at` plus like 100 years.

It's important here to make it generate the same token for the same input parameters from run-to-run or the header will be different which will cause a **new pact** to be considered by the broker. This dramatically changes the approach - you basically need to verify **every new pact** each time.

On the question of handling exceptions. Do not cheat like this

```
httpRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi");
```

Give your client class code a chance to pass the values naturally, pass it somehow or mock using the same `JwtTestHelper`